# backbonejs model.toJSON() can't get correct output, with backbone.iobind

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

backbone Model,board:

```
 define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'collections/lists',
  'iobind',
  'iosync'
], function( _, Backbone, Lists,ioBind,ioSync) {

  var BoardModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'board',
    noIoBind: false,
    socket: io.connect(''),
    idAttribute: '_id',

    defaults: {
      title: 'One Thousand and One Nights'
    },

    initialize: function() {
      this.id = 1;
      this.lists = new Lists;
      this.socket.emit('joinBoard',this.id);

      _.bindAll(this, 'getBoard');
      this.ioBind('initBoard', this.getBoard, this);
    },

    getBoard: function(data){
      this.set(data.data.board[0]);
    }
  });

  return BoardModel;
});
```

backbone View: boardView:

```
var IndexView = Backbone.View.extend({

    // Instead of generating a new element, bind to the existing elements in the HTML.
    el: '#board',

    // Board template html
    template: Mustache.render(Template.board),

    events: {

    },

    initialize: function() {
      //Init Data
      this.model = new Board();
//      var lists = {
//        lists: [
//          {name: "To Do",
//            cards:[
//              {name: "Art work for A."},
//              {name: "B Prototype."},
//              {name: "C prototype."}
//            ]
//          },
//          {name: "Doing",
//            cards: [
//              {name: "Art work for A."}
//            ]
//          },
//          {name: "Done"}
//        ]
//      }
//      var partial = {card: Template.card_in_list};
//      var listHtml = Mustache.render(Template.list,lists,partial);
//      template = $(this.template).find('.list-area').append(listHtml);
    },

    render: function() {

      console.log(this.model);
      console.log(this.model.toJSON());

      var partial = {card: Template.card_in_list};
      var listHtml = Mustache.render(Template.list,this.model,partial);
      template = $(this.template).find('.list-area').append(listHtml);
      this.$el.html(template);
    }

  });
```

in View function: render function, the console.log get different result.
console.log(this.model) can get correct object result:

```
child
_callbacks: Object
_changing: false
_escapedAttributes: Object
_ioEvents: Object
_pending: Object
_previousAttributes: Object
_silent: Object
attributes: Object
__v: 0
_id: "50b750a7795f285d4e000014"
created: "2012-11-29T12:10:15.269Z"
description: "simple is better, but not simpler"
dueDate: "2012-11-29T12:10:15.269Z"
lists: Array[6]
status: true
title: "test board unique"
__proto__: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c1"
getBoard: function () { [native code] }
id: "50b750a7795f285d4e000014"
lists: child
__proto__: ctor
```

but this.model.toJSON() only get model default values:

```
Object
title: "One Thousand and One Nights"
__proto__: Object
```

it confuse me. anyone know why reason the same model get different result.

Comment: Hi man! I saw you were asking here https://github.com/logicalparadox/backbone.iobind/issues/26 How did you manage to solve the "Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined" problem? Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found i  trigger boardView.render twice. when i change code:

```
a = new boardView;
a.render();
```

to

```
a = new boardView;
```

i got the thing done.

by the way thanks  Marcel Falliere's comments.

Answer (score 0):

In a Backbone Model, your business values (description, title ...) are store in the `attributes` attribute. When you call `toJSON()` on your model, what it does is it takes the `attributes` values, and remove the Backbone.Model object framework's functions and attributes.

When you manually want to set model attributes, you want to use `set`. I don't know what is in you `data.data` object, so you should check the doc : http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set

> **set** `model.set(attributes, [options])`
>
> Set a hash of attributes (one or
>   many) on the model. If any of the attributes change the models state,
>   a "change" event will be triggered, unless {silent: true} is passed as
>   an option. Change events for specific attributes are also triggered,
>   and you can bind to those as well, for example: change:title, and
>   change:content. You may also pass individual keys and values.
>
> note.set({title: "March 20", content: "In his eyes she eclipses..."});
>
> book.set("title", "A Scandal in Bohemia"); If the model has a validate
>   method, it will be validated before the attributes are set, no changes
>   will occur if the validation fails, and set will return false.
>   Otherwise, set returns a reference to the model. You may also pass an
>   error callback in the options, which will be invoked instead of
>   triggering an "error" event, should validation fail. If {silent: true}
>   is passed as an option, the validation is deferred until the next
>   change.

Comment: I already get correct attributes successfully, but in my view.render function, i use console.log to output my attributes, it show correctly, but when i toJSON the attributes, it directly give me model's default value, it very confuse me. Do you have any comments?

Comment: no your model is wrongly build. why ? because I see there are `description`, `dueDate`, `lists`, `status` and MOREOVER there is a `title` attribute that is not the default value you specified. Look at it : the default value you specified is in yourmodel.attributes.title !! So as far as I can tell, my comment is right. Your model attributes are wrongly set...